# RestTemplateBuilder bean

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, resttemplate

My application interfaces with different rest endpoints and each one needs a specialized RestTemplate object. I am using RestTemplateBuilder to create each of the RestTemplate objects. Is it ok to clone the RestTemplateBuilder object provided by spring boot and make the changes?

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
@Bean
public RestTemplate googleRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthorization("user", "pwd123").build();
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate twitterRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.setConnectTimeout(5000).build();
}
}
```

Here, i get the singleton builder bean injected to both the bean  methods.  The problem i am trying to overcome is that the mutating of the same builder object. In my example, my 2nd rest template does not need basic authorization but i inadvertently  get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can differentiate your RestTemplates using `@Qualifier` annotation like below.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("googleRestTemplate")
  public RestTemplate googleRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthorization("user", "pwd123").build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("twitterRestTemplate")
  public RestTemplate twitterRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.setConnectTimeout(5000).build();
  }
}
```

Then you can use any of RestTemplate beans in your controllers with these @Qualifiers.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("googleRestTemplate")
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of qualifier to differentiate different rest template beans - my question is about rest template builder beans.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that?
Add a `config` class:

```
@Configuration
class Config {
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

inside your `Controller` that will consume your end-points:

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTempl;

@RequestMapping(value = "/consume", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void samplePostMethod() {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("Data", headers);
    RequestDetails requestDetails = new RequestDetails("http://localhost:8082/endpoint1", HttpMethod.POST);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTempl.exchange(requestDetails.getUrl(), requestDetails.getRequestType(),
            entity, String.class);

    RequestDetails requestDetailss = new RequestDetails("http://localhost:8082/endpoint2", HttpMethod.POST);
    ResponseEntity<String> responses = restTempl.exchange(requestDetailss.getUrl(), requestDetailss.getRequestType(),
            entity, String.class);

    logger.log("{} {}", response, responses);
    return response.getBody();
}
```

Comment: I have added a code snippet and explanation  about the  problem.

Comment: What about changing the scope of the bean from singleton to request. See the update above

Comment: But if you need to make the calls to these endpoints with the same request to your application, the above solution won't work. I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: My idea was to clone the resttemplatebuilder in both the bean methods so that the original builder remains pristine.

Comment: no, you can't do that. If you need customization, you use `RestTemplateCustomizer` And you don't need to do that anyway. As per the documentation, every call to the methods of `RestTemplateBuilder ` returns a new `RestTemplateBuilder ` instance. So this basically means, you should have one instance for google and one for twitter. I suspect you don't even call your second bean. Could you check that by adding some logger?