# Multiple RestTemplateBuilders in Context forms cycle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My application makes REST calls to 2 different web services. The first one uses basic authentication and the second does not. I would like to define a RestTemplateBuilder bean with the basic auth credentials configured & use it for the basic-auth case and use the default Spring configured RestTemplateBuilder for the non-basic-auth case.

But defining the custom RestTemplateBuilder bean fails context load(details below).

Bean definition:

```
@Configuration
class RestTemplateBuilderConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplateBuilder customRestTemplateBuilder(RestTemplateBuilder springConfiguredRestTemplateBuilder) {
        return
            springConfiguredRestTemplateBuilder
                .basicAuthentication("user", "password");
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Context load failure:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  customRestTemplateBuilder defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/RestTemplateBuilderConfig.class]
└─────┘
```

As I understand, the spring initialized bean should be injected into `customRestTemplateBuilder(...)` and the return value should result in a new bean with name `customRestTemplateBuilder`. Appreciate any pointers on what could be going wrong?

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51047814/636334) suggest defining RestTemplate beans. But that would prevent usage of `RestClientTest` in my tests.

I could inject the Spring initialized RestTemplateBuilder into my services and set the credentials before `restTemplateBuilder.build()` in each of the services. But then the logic to set the credentials will be distributed across the services (violating DRY).

Defining a new RestTemplateBuilder resolves the issue but Spring initialization is lost.

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplateBuilder customRestTemplateBuilder() {
        return
            new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .basicAuthentication("user", "password");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice but define 2 bean in your context, which maybe share the same initialization logic by defining a init method for both. As bean level reusing is not possible as shows in your example.

Answer (score 0):

RestTemplateBuilder is used to build single RestTemplates.

Easiest is to just build two restTemplates and use a @Qualifier for each RestTemplate.